How to achieve concurrency with python telegram bot module
I am using python telegram bot module to create a bot that takes an image in Braille as an input, translates it then returns the English translation. The method responsible for the translation is defined as follows,
async def start_translation(update: Update, context: CallbackContext):
    # translation logic
    return translated_text

The problem here is that this method takes too long to finish. So, when a user sends an image to the bot while another user has already sent an image and it is being translated, the second user has to wait until the first user is done. How can I employ parallel processing in my code so that multiple users can translate at the same time? I have tried to use threading module but it seems like it is not supported with async functions. Below is how the translation process starts:
def create_handle_photo(oVoice, oCorrect, oInference, current_dir):
    async def handle_photo(update: Update, context: CallbackContext):
        image_path = await get_image(update, context, current_dir) # download the image
        oProcessImage = ProcessImage(image_path)
        text = await start_translation(update, context, oProcessImage, oInference, oCorrect)
        if text != '': 
            await generate_voice(update, context, current_dir, oVoice, text)
        await clean_up(current_dir, image_path) #delete downloaded files
    return handle_photo

def main():
   app = ApplicationBuilder().token(TOKEN).build()
   handle_photo_handler = create_handle_photo(oVoice, oCorrect, oInference, current_dir)
   app.add_handler(MessageHandler(filters.PHOTO, handle_photo_handler)) # handle photo
   app.run_polling()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()

The input and output of the bot:


https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot/wiki/Concurrency

@CallMeStag i have tried the solutions in the docs but they didn't work. for example when i run a command while an image is being translated it will be executed only after start_translation function is done

better show minimal working code where you use threading. Without code we can only send you to some tutorials. or write examples which works for us but may not work for you (because you may have more complex code).
